# How to insert value in database using bean class in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, javabeans

Hi  iam tring to insert value in database using bean class in jsp form and i am able to this but i am getting little bit problem whenever i insert value in table  null value also insert with them i tried  not i am not able to get  that where i m wrong please solve my problem

my bean.java

```
package com.javabean;


import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class bean 
{

    private String msgid;
    private String message;
    private Connection connection=null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;
    private Statement st = null;
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/JspBean";


    public bean() 
    {
         try {
             // Load the database driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // Get a Connection to the database
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception is ;"+e);
            }

    }  
    public void setmsgid(String msgid)
    {
        this.msgid = msgid;
    }

    public String getmsgid()
    {
        return (this.msgid);
    }

    public void setmessage(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getmessage()
    {
        return (this.message);
    }

    public void insert()
    {

       try
       {
            String sql = "insert into login(messageid,message) values('"+msgid+"','"+message+"')";
            Statement s = connection.createStatement();
            s.executeUpdate (sql);
            s.close ();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception is ;"+e);
        }
    }

}
```

here is my jspbean.jsp file

```
<%@ page language="Java" import="java.sql.*" %>

<html>
    <head><title>JSP with Javabeans</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#ffccff">
<h1>JSP using JavaBeans example</h1>
    <form name="form1" method="POST">

         ID&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input type="text" name ="msgid"> <br>
         Message<input type="text" name ="message"> <br>
         <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input type = "submit" value="Submit">
         <jsp:useBean id="sample" class="com.javabean.bean" scope="page">
            <jsp:setProperty name="sample" property="*"/>
        </jsp:useBean>
    </form>
    <% sample.insert();%>
</body>
</html>
```

how can i achieve this please solve  my problem
hanks in advance
T

Comment: Off subject comment:  You really shouldn't be doing DB manipulations in the UI code.  This is typically frowned upon for many reasons, not least of which it's almost impossible to debug.  Also, you should use `PreparedStatement`s and pass in the values to your insert as parameters.  Concatenation like you are doing leads to problems like SQL injection.  Enough of my soapbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your doing some mistake:

```
public void setmsgid(String msgid)
    {
        this.msgid = msgid;
    }
    public String getmsgid()
    {
        return (this.msgid);
    }
```

you should change as:

```
public String getmsgid()
    {
        return msgid;
    }
public void setmsgid(String msgid)
    {
        this.msgid = msgid;
    }
```

and add this one also:

```
public String toString()
{
    return "User[msgid="+msgid+",message="+message+"];

}
```

you should must change this one:

```
insert into login(username,password) values('"+msgid+"','"+message+"')";
```

---

```
insert into login(username,password) values(?,?)";
```

**update:**

```
insert into login(messageid,message) values(?,?)";
```

Comment: where should i add this

Comment: first you should change the insert part and then compile

Comment: i changed in insert part as u said but now there is no value is inserting  in db

Comment: i had one doubt, where did you use the username and password

Comment: i used username and password in table field name

Comment: table filed means  number of fields in database table

Comment: very simple i want to insert value in database and nothing else

Comment: k, insert means username, password or otherwise, messageid , message.

Comment: messageid and message

Comment: then way did you use the username and password in the database..k now u should tell me how many field and what the name of the field in db.

Comment: i have changed my code little bit i changed username and password with messageid and message

Comment: now only to field in database  messageid and message

Comment: iam not getting this line where i have to put this   public String toString()
{
    return "User[msgid="+msgid+",etc]

}

Comment: i copied but it is showing message  unclosed string literal